# Should not we use "operation" instead of "operating" in this definition?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

I read a definition of vivisection which was:

> Operating on live animals

If operating is gerund we can't use preposition after it. Is it an exception?

Comment: Should there be operating or operation?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you can use a preposition after a gerund. Gerunds can take objects and adjuncts just like finite verbs. Examples:

> I like eating bananas (direct object)
>
> I like skating on ice (adjunct of place)
>
> I like giving presents to people (direct and indirect object)
>
> I don't like depending on other people (indirect object introduced by 'on')